# Show that a single binomial probability can be written as the sum of two binomial probabilities

Tags: probability

I am trying to prove that the sum of two independent binomial probabilities with the same parameter (probability of success in a single trial) is equivalent to a binomial probability with the same parameter , but an index (number of trials) and number of successes that is equivalent to the sum of the indexes from the first two binomial probabilities and the sum of the number of successes from the first two binomial probabilities.

I think the basic idea is that the binomial probability of an event can be broken up and calculated in two "chunks" which can be summed to find the desired binomial probability.

Sorry for not including any mathematical operators in this post; I am unfamiliar with how they are actually written in this type of a post.

Edit:
${n \choose x} \pi^x (1 - \pi)^{n-x} = {a \choose y} \pi^y (1 - \pi)^{a-y} + {b \choose z} \pi^z(1 - \pi)^{b-z}$ where $a+b=n$ and $y+z=x$

Comment: Try to write the formulas as best you can, and we will try to edit them later. Bad formulas are still better than no formulas at all. If you need help, see this page: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of successes when an experiment is repeated independently $m$  times, with probability of success $p$ each time. Now suppose the experiment is done again $n$ times.

Then $X$ has binomial distribution, parameters $m$ and $p$, while $Y$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $p$.

It is clear that $X+Y$ is the number of successes when the experiment is repeated independently $m+n$ times. So $X+Y$ has binomial distribution with parameters $m+n$ and $p$.

**Remark:** One can also do the problem the hard way. Let $W=X+Y$. Then 
$$\Pr(W=w)=\sum_{i=0}^w \Pr(X=i)\Pr(Y=w-i).$$
Using the usual binomial distribution formulas, we get
$$\Pr(W=w)=\sum_{i=0}^w\binom{m}{i}p^i(1-p)^{w-i}\binom{n}{w-i}p^{w-i}(1-p)^{n-(w-i)}.$$
Manipulation of the above formula yields, after a while,
$$\Pr(W=w)=\binom{m+n}{w}p^w(1-p)^{m+n-w}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that this is the concept, but is there a way to mathematically prove it?

Comment: I have sketched a manipulational argument, which I consider inferior, since it is less conceptual. Almost all the steps are there, or are easy. The one thing that takes work is the binomial coefficient identity $\sum_0^w \binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{w-i}=\binom{m+n}{w}$. The easy proof of this is conceptual, we have $m$ girls and $n$ boys, and want to pick $w$ people. There are also manipulational arguments. The easiest is using $(1+x)^m(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{m+n}$ and the Binomial Theorem.